# Save video track names as a preset

Tags: video, premiere, setup

I'm in Premiere Pro CC 2019 13.1.2, and want to save named video tracks as a preset.  This can be easily done with Audio as per image, but I think I must be missing how to set up a preset with named video tracks.  How can I do this?  I can't find a fat lot about it online at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest versions of Premiere Pro CC, you can now rename video tracks by right clicking them:

[image]